# Workload Scheduler: File transfer job submitted on a Windows agent ends in error

Tags: file, jobs, transfer, workload-scheduler

I am trying to submit a file transfer job on a Windows machine where the TWS agent is installed. The agent works correctly and I can detect no problems, but the file transfer regularly fails....  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When endpoint protection software is active on a Windows agent workstation, the FTP connection is blocked by Java. A Java technology bug reporting this issue can be accessed at http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7077696